# Can i conditionally add an object in the select section of a linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of nodes where each node contains a list of boards and each board contains a list of devices. I'm writing a linq statement to get all the devices that have their Installed field enabled. I want to return the node number from the node list, return the board number (slot number) from the board list, and I want to return the entire device object from the device list. I created the DEVICE_TABLE class to hold this information and the code below works - somewhat.

```
var list = from n in s.propNodeList
           from b in n.propBoardList
           from d in b.propDeviceList
           .Where(d => d.propDeviceInstalled == DEVICE_INSTALLED_Types.Enabled)

            select (new DEVICE_TABLE()
            {
                 propNodeNumber = n.propNodeNumber,       //int
                 propSlotNumber = b.propBoardNumber,      //int
                 propDevice = d,                          //DEVICE 
             });
```

The problem is that in the DEVICE_TABLE class propDevice is specified as a DEVICE but the 'd' value could be a number of different types of devices that are derived from DEVICE.

The following line does not work but I would like to do something like this. I would like to cast the appropriate device to propDevice

```
if d.propDeviceTag == DEVICE_TAG_Types.D1
    propDevice = (D1)d 
else if d.propDeviceTag == DEVICE_TAG_Types.D2
    propDevice = (D2)d 
else if d.propDeviceTag == DEVICE_TAG_Types.D3
    propDevice = (D3)d 
else
    propDevice = (D4)d
```

I created a linq statement to specifically get a list of D1 devices, for example, but I think there must be a way to write a single linq statement to perform this task. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: what is wrong with `propDevice = d` if they are derived type this should work just fine

Comment: Franck - you are correct. My input test data was incomplete which made it look like the code was incorrect. Thanks